# Gerando um txt com números aleatórios repete os números

Tags: c#, .net, random

O programa tem que gerar 10 letras e depois pular uma linha com mais 10 letras diferentes.

Eu usei o `Random()` e consegui gerar 10 letras aleatórias, só que depois simplesmente as linhas se repetem. Tipo, não gera letras aleatórias, apenas se repetem.

Eu preciso que a cada linha uma nova sequencia de letras aleatórias fosse formada.

```
public void rodar()
    {
        Random dudm = new Random(DateTime.Now.Millisecond);
        StreamWriter str = new StreamWriter("arquivo.txt");
        int contador = 0;
        int num = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
        string resultado = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
        {
            while (contador < 11)
            {                   
                    int rnd = dudm.Next(1, 26);
                    if (rnd == 1)
                    {
                        resultado = resultado + "a";
                        contador++;
                    }
                    else if (rnd == 2)
                    {
                        resultado = resultado + "b";
                        contador++;
                    }
                    else if (rnd == 3)
                    {
                        resultado = resultado + "c";
                        contador++;
                    }
                    else if (rnd == 4)
                    {
                        resultado = resultado + "d";
                        contador++;
                    }
                    else if (rnd == 5)
                    {
                        resultado = resultado + "e";
                        contador++;
                    }
                    else if (rnd == 6)
                    {
                        resultado = resultado + "f";
                        contador++;
                    }
                    else if (rnd == 7)
                    {
                        resultado = resultado + "g";
                        contador++;
                    }
                    else if (rnd == 8)
                    {
                        resultado = resultado + "h";
                        contador++;
                    }
                    else if (rnd == 9)
                    {
                        resultado = resultado + "i";
                        contador++;
                    }
                    else if (rnd == 10)
                    {
                        resultado = resultado + "j";
                        contador++;
                    }
                    else if (rnd == 11)
                    {
                        resultado = resultado + "k";
                        contador++;
                    }
                    else if (rnd == 12)
                    {
                        resultado = resultado + "l";
                        contador++;

                    }
                    else if (rnd == 13)
                    {
                        resultado = resultado + "m";
                        contador++;
                    }
                    else if (rnd == 14)
                    {
                        resultado = resultado + "n";
                        contador++;
                    }
                    else if (rnd == 15)
                    {
                        resultado = resultado + "o";
                        contador++;
                    }
                    else if (rnd == 16)
                    {
                        resultado = resultado + "p";
                        contador++;
                    }
                    else if (rnd == 17)
                    {
                        resultado = resultado + "q";
                        contador++;
                    }
                    else if (rnd == 18)
                    {
                        resultado = resultado + "r";
                        contador++;
                    }
                    else if (rnd == 19)
                    {
                        resultado = resultado + "s";
                        contador++;

                    }
                    else if (rnd == 20)
                    {
                        resultado = resultado + "t";
                        contador++;
                    }
                    else if (rnd == 21)
                    {
                        resultado = resultado + "u";
                        contador++;
                    }
                    else if (rnd == 22)
                    {
                        resultado = resultado + "v";
                        contador++;
                    }
                    else if (rnd == 23)
                    {
                        resultado = resultado + "w";
                        contador++;
                    }
                    else if (rnd == 24)
                    {
                        resultado = resultado + "x";
                        contador++;
                    }
                    else if (rnd == 25)
                    {
                        resultado = resultado + "y";
                        contador++;
                    }
                    else if (rnd == 26)
                    {
                        resultado = resultado + "z";
                        contador++;
                    }
            }
            str.WriteLine(resultado);
        }
        str.Close();
        if (MessageBox.Show("txt feito. Deseja vê-la?", this.Text, MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Information) == DialogResult.Yes )
        {
            Process.Start(@"arquivo.txt");
        }
        button1.Enabled = true;

    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Esse código tem alguns problemas. O maior deles é que está iniciando a semente aleatória todas as vezes que vai usar então causa a repetição. Você deve acionar a semente uma vez e depois consumir. Você só percebe isso rodando várias vezes.

Há um problema de performance e consumo com tanta concatenação, o certo é construir o texto, eu mudei isso. Inclusive limpei o texto no fim de cada laço interno para não ir acumulando.

Ainda há um problema que se a pessoa digitar algo que não seja um número válido irá quebrar sua aplicação. Eu fiz ela não fazer nada, mas você pode colocar uma mensagem de erro ou qualquer outra coisa. Eu criei um campo na classe só para testar, você continua usando o objeto do o formulário. Obviamente eu simplifiquei para mostrar o teste sem precisar do Windows Forms.

Eu também mandei colocar na tela só para testar, você mantém escrevendo no arquivo.

E eu ainda simplifiquei porque você tem ali um `for` dentro de `for` não sei porque optou por um `while`, e não tem necessidade de fazer tanto `if`, é só usar matemática.

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using static System.Console;

public class Program {
    public static Random Rand = new Random(DateTime.Now.Millisecond);
    public static string Text = "10";
    public static void Main() => Rodar();
    public static void Rodar() {
        if (!int.TryParse(Text, out var num)) return;
        var resultado = new StringBuilder(11);
        for (var i = 0; i < num; i++) {
            for (var j = 0; j < 11; j++) resultado.Append((char)(Rand.Next(1, 26) + 97));
            WriteLine(resultado);
            resultado.Clear();
        }
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/jooWAu). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/2luppo). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Math/RandomChar.cs).

Answer (score 1):

Presta atenção na sua string resultado, ela é definida antes de entrar no **for loop**, so que dentro ela não é reiniciada, ou seja:

O seu loop reponsável por gerar a palavra com 10 letras aleatórias, depois que escreve no .txt, ele recomeça com a mesma string **resultado** anterior, e como ela ja tem o tamanho esperado, o programa so imprime novamente.

Para corrigir o erro basta reiniciar a string resultado após cada escrita.

**Obs:** Seu contador pode ser colocado fora das condicionais, evitando assim repetição de código.